# Android, EditText, prevent line wrapping

Tags: android

I have an EditText component:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/LogDisplay"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:ems="10"
android:fadeScrollbars="true"
android:gravity="start|top"
android:importantForAutofill="no"
android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
android:isScrollContainer="true"
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
android:overScrollMode="always"
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:singleLine="true"
android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
tools:ignore="LabelFor,SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
```

Can't get the result to show a horizontal scroll bar and lines of text to show full length without hyphens.

Help me please.

Comment: have you tried with `android:maxLines="1"` instead of  `android:singleLine="true"`, with `android:scrollHorizontally="true"`?

Comment: I tried this option, it doesn't work. If it were that simple, I wouldn't ask :)

Answer (score 0):

To add a horizontal scroll to edit text, add this to your edit text:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et_name_signup"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but android:scrollHorizontally="true" is already added and doesn't work properly anyway.

Comment: remove all the other code. just try that one I have given in my edited answer

Comment: In this variant, there is only one line and it doesn't wrap, but the horizontal scrollbar still doesn't appear. And I need many lines, not just one, just without hyphens. Thank you very much for your attention, sorry for bothering you.